# Is there a JavaScript proposal for an operator to apply a function to every item in a collection?

Tags: javascript

`Function#map` applies a function to each item in a collection and returns a new collection.

Is there an ECMAScript proposal for an operator to do the same?

Comment: _operator to do the same_. What do you mean?

Comment: There had been array comprehensions, but seemed dead last time I heard anything about it. That's a good thing, IMO. Too much redundancy.

Comment: "Array comprehensions" was the term I had forgotten the name. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a combination of

- [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for building a new object of single objects as parts,
- [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for taking an array as parameters,
- [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) for getting an array with key/value arrays,
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for doing the work with key and values,
- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for separating an array in key and value variables,
- [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) for getting a new object with a given key.

```js
var object = { a: 1, b: 2 },
    result = Object.assign(...Object.entries(object).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v * 2 })));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I thought you'd at least get `new.target` in there?

Comment: @Ben, do you need to use it as constructor somehow?

Comment: Sorry, I confess I thought this was a joke! Peace.